# How to use useLayoutEffect hook

Tags: react-native, layout, state, effect, rerender

Code here:

```
const insets = useSafeAreaInsets()
const { params} = useRoute()
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false)
const [info, setInfo] = useState(INITIAL_INFO)
const [isMarked As Favorite, setIsMarked As Favorite] = useState(false)
const { favorites } = useSelector((state) => state. favorites)
useLayoutEffect (() => {
  navigation.setOptions({
    headerTitle: params.title,
    headerRight: () => (
      <Icon
        name={isMarked As Favorite ? 'heart': 'heart-outline'}
        size={20}
        color={isMarked As Favorite ? colors.primary : colors.black}
        style={headerIconStyle}
        onPress={() => {
          if (isMarked As Favorite) {
            dispatch (removeFromFavorite({ ...params?.item }))
            setIsMarkedAs Favorite(false)
            return
          }
          dispatch (addToFavorite({ ...params?.item }))
        }}
      />
    )
  })
}, [navigation, params, info, dispatch, isMarked As Favorite])
```

I have headerRight in useLayoutEffect hook.  I want to re-render it on the basis of state change.

How can i do that ?

I have passed state as dependency array in useLayoutEffect hook but it's not working.
But My icon in headerRight is not re-rendering.

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: The code has been uploaded.

Comment: Can you try to use `useEffect` instead of `useLayoutEffect` ?

Comment: Thanks @devpolo.
The above code is working fine, but there was an issue in another part of the code.

Comment: What is this _isMarked As Favorite_ is it a type? Because it is a simple boolean right, currently it looks a bit like type casting in TypeScript? Have you tried rendering some text instead of a icon?

Comment: @RubenSmn No.....

Comment: No you have not tried anything but the Icon or no its not type casting? If it's not type casting, please update your code with the correctly formatted code.

Comment: @RubenSmn, I had not tried to render some text.